# Login Form freezes when SQL Server is not running

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Login Form that checks **AutoLogInStatus** in database. If the **AutoLogInStatus** is set to `true` the main form will show if `false` the login form will show.

This the code in my `Form_Load` events:

```
 if (Convert.ToBoolean(UserAutoLogon()) == true)
    {
          this.Hide();
          frmMain.Show();
    }
 else
    {
          this.Show();
    }
```

All works good, except if the SQL server is not running. The login forms shows with all white  and it freezes.

How will I handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using async-await so that your UI thread is not blocked while the SQL connection is being established:

```
  private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frmMain = new frmMain();

        var result = await UserAutoLogon();

        if (result == true)
        {
            this.Hide();
            frmMain.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Show();
        }
    }

 private Task<bool> UserAutoLogon()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000); // Db connection delay
            return true;
        });
    }
```

**UPDATE**

The UserAutoLogon() method's implementation was given so that it simulates the delay - you may use await connection.OpenAsync() as suggested by [Scott Chamberlain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain) in the comments.

Comment: instead of `Task.Run` a much better option is use `await connection.OpenAsync()` when you open the connection.

Comment: yes, absolutely, I just used the Task.Run to simulate the delay as the method implementation was not shared..have updated my answer, calling out your suggestion! :)

Comment: It's not likely that you're handling a `button1_Click` before the form is shown. It would have been nice for the OP to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, how will I use it in Form Load event?

Comment: just mark your form load event as async and move the code there..have updated my answer..and it's better to show an indication to the user that the logon is in progress before awaiting the UserAutoLogon() method.